# Unable to toggle using xs device using twitter bootstrap 3

Tags: ios, toggle, twitter-bootstrap-3, navbar

I have the following snippet. I am unable to toggle the data values in smaller resolution though the button appears on the scree. No data has been displayed when I click on toggle button.

```
     <div class="container">  
          <nav class="navbar navbar-default" role="navigation">  
        <!-- Brand and toggle get grouped for better mobile display -->
        <div class="navbar-header">
          <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-headerdata-collapse">
            <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
          </button>
        </div>

        <!-- Collect the nav links, forms, and other content for toggling -->
        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse navbar-headerdata-collapse">
          <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
            <li class="active"><a href="#">About Us</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Contact Us</a></li>
            <form class="navbar-form  navbar-right" role="search"> 
            <div class="form-group">
                <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Search">
            </div>
                <button class="btn btn-default" type="submit"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-search"></i></button>
            </form>
          </ul>
        </div><!-- /.navbar-collapse -->
    </nav>
</div>
```

Can someone help resolving the issue?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

This was just because of improper linking of bootstrap JS.!